# How to stop alert notifications in (ios 7) objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have implemented remote notification in objective-c . But my problem is I want to stop alert notification .Blow my code which I am using

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
      IRemoteNotificationTypeSound ];
```

but I still getting banner notification . and `didreceiveremotenotification`method is successfully called

but when I change the code to

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
      IRemoteNotificationTypenone ];
```

Then I receive no alert, no sound, and also `didreceiveremotenotification` not called. I want that app not show alert banner. But it  must call `didreceiveremotenotification` in background mode, because in `didreceiveremotenotification` I am receiving necessary data 
.

Comment: I think only user can achieve that with setting your app's alert style to none in Setting->Notification Center.

Comment: Where did you put these code? `appDidFinishLaunching:`?